# いや、端から見ようとしてないのか What does this mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, japanese-to-english

Context : 2 characters talking about who is the culprit of a crime and why MC was falsely arrested by the police

G1: 最後の事件……逃げ道は、完全に封鎖されていた.

だけど煙のように犯人は消えてしまった.

だから、君が犯人だと断定されてしまったわけだけど.

皆、もう一つの可能性を見逃している。いや、端から見ようとしてないのか (I don't understand this line)

G2: まさか

G1: うん。犯人は、警察内部にいる

Can anyone give me English translation of いや、端から見ようとしてないのか
My guess "No,maybe I should say that no one have looked at this case from a big picture perspective / objectively " ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This 端から is not はしから but [はなから](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%AB%AF%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89).
- The implicit object of 見る is もう一つの可能性, not the case.
- You have somehow ignored the ようとする construction.

> 皆、もう一つの可能性を見逃している。いや、端から見ようとしてないのか。
> Everyone has overlooked another possibility. Rather, they may have no intention to look at it from the beginning.

Comment: so G1 means that no one (of the police force) has even trying to take a look at that possibility (that MC is falsely accused ) ?
Or that "possibility" is that one person inside the police is the culprit ?

Comment: @4chanuser Don't they amount to the same thing in this context?

Comment: yeah you're right